# Objective-C – Expected identifier error

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I'm getting an expected identifier error when I try to compile my code.

careerURL is setup like this in .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *careerURL;
```

And synthesized like this in .m file:

```
@synthesize careerURL;
```

I really do not understand what is the issue here. The exact code works in another viewcontroller.

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should either use dot `.` syntax,

```
NSString *wtf = self.careerURL;
```

Or Objective-C message syntax,

```
NSString *wtf = [self careerURL];
```

*Not both at the same time*.

Comment: Yes. Thanks this worked for me. I got the basic idea on this.

Answer (score 5):

You should write:

```
 NSString *wtf = self.careerURL;
```

When you are writing `[object method]` it is expected that you want to call method `method` from object `object`. If you want just access some value (that is defined as `@property`) you can type:

```
[self nameOfValue];
```

or

```
self.nameOfValue;
```