# iBeacon Errors: Setting up major and minor id's

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

This seems like a relatively easy question but I am getting errors. I am working on an iBeacon project which will display different messages to the user depending on which iBeacon they are closest to. I already set up major and minor values from the transmitter and then tried calling them in a different class but I get errors saying "Expected Identifier"

```
self.majorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.major];
    self.minorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.minor];
    self.accuracyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", beacon.accuracy];
    if (([beacon.minor] == 1) && ([beacon.major] == 2) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar)) {
        self.distanceLabel.text = @"Good Bye";
        self.distanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
```

Is there something i am doing wrong here??

Comment: I'd quite like to see a cut and paste of the actual error message but this could be a case of mixing the dot (.) and message syntax (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847122/objective-c-expected-identifier-error-driving-me-crazy). So try `[beacon minor] == 1` or `beacon.minor == 1` instead.

Comment: Ok here is what the error says
     if (([[beacon.minor] : Expected identifier
integerValue] == 1) &&
        ([[beacon.major] : Expected identifier                integerValue] == 2) &&
(beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar))
    {
        self.distanceLabel.text = @"Good Bye";
        self.distanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

Comment: IityFar))t says that right after the if statement.I set up the major and minor value as self.majorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.major];
    
    self.minorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.minor];

Comment: `1.` Please add the properly formatted error to your question (helps everyone) and `2.` Have you tried my suggestion concerning the mixing of properties and methods syntax (i.e. remove the square brackets around `beacon.minor` and `beacon.major`)?

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked. I removed the square brackets around beacon.minor and beacon.major and it worked like a charm!! Thanks again

Comment: I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which line is giving an error, and what is the exact text of the error? I'm guessing it's the if statement, since that's the only line of your code that includes beacon minor and major values.

What is the variable "beacon"? Is it of type CLBeacon? I would assume so.

The major and minor value properties of a CLBeacon object (and also of a CLBeaconRegion object) are NSNumbers, not integers. Thus your if statement should read

```
if (([[beacon.minor] integerValue] == 1) && 
   ([[beacon.major] integerValue] == 2) && 
   (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar)) 
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you Duncan yes the value property is a CLBeacon. I updated the code to what your suggested and I still get the same error.if (([[beacon.minor] integerValue] == 1) &&
        ([[beacon.major] integerValue] == 2) &&
it says Expected Identifier right on that code

Comment: Dunno. Edit your question and post the entire method, as well as the relevant sections of the .h file that declare the instance variables you're using. Also take a screenshot of the compiler error and post that. It should put a caret mark right on the part of the line that is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks It got resolved. I was calling them as integers instead of NSNumber. Once I changed that and fixed my syntax it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Hugh Mbaezue, isn't that what I said to do?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message: `Expected identifier` it appears you are mixing the property dot (.) and message syntax.

Change your code:

`if (([beacon.minor] == 1) && ([beacon.major] == 2) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar)) {
...
}`

to either property (.) syntax (removing the `[]` brackets):

`if ((beacon.minor == 1) && (beacon.major == 2) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar)) {
...
}`

or method syntax (removing the `.`):

`if (([beacon minor] == 1) && ([beacon major] == 2) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar)) {
...
}`